# Use LISTAGG to select multiple rows on joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I have the following two tables
Table 1 - User

```
ID UserName
001 abc
002 bcd
003 def
```

TAble 2 - Values

```
ID Tag Price
001 start 1
001 middle 2
001 end 3
002 start 3
002 end 4
003 start 1
003 middle 2
003 end 3
```

I'm interested with values tagged with "start" and "end", i.e., the expected result is:

```
001 abc 1, 2
002 bcd 3, 4
003 def 1, 3
```

Note: I need the UserName in table 1.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select u.id, u.name, listagg(price, ', ') within group (order by price) as prices
from user u left outer join
     values v
     on u.id = v.id and v.tag in ('start', 'end')
group by u.id, u.name;
```